# Is it necessary to do Fake Papers after getting sufficiently far enough in Family Matters?

Tags: the-witcher-3

As the title says, I'm pretty far along in the Family Matters quest - at the point where I need to go talk to the Baron's daughter - and he gives me a pass to do so.  My question is: having done this, is there any non-experience related benefit to doing the Fake Papers sidequest? I already helped out the guy's brother-in-law, but I'm not sure if it's still worth it to even pay for the papers (I'm kinda strapped for crowns) if the Baron gave me papers to get into the city already.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: There is, of course, the benefit of doing the quest just for the sake of doing the quest. Does it take you to a part of the map you've not yet explored? Do you meet a character you've not yet met? Do you have conversations that deepen your enjoyment of the rest of the game? Hard to reduce that sort of stuff to simple "yes/no" answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't need to do the Fake Papers quest if you already have the papers from the Baron. Helping his brother-in-law is the only thing involved.